# How to change the distance between lines of grid?

Tags: highcharts

i have

```
  yAxis: {

        reversed: true,
        categories: ['0','10','20','30','50','80','130','210','340','550','700'],                       
        labels: {
                    format: '{value} km',
                    enabled: true
                },
        title: {
                text: "Depth"
                }
         },
```

but i want to change the distance between the lines of grid (line value 0km, line value 10km ecc ecc)

Is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

These two should work. Use the one that fits you better.

```
        tickPositions
        tickPositioner
```

Ejamples:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfbffqe7/

http://jsfiddle.net/0xb2c8e5/

**Edit:**
This should do the trick of what you requested in the comments.
http://jsfiddle.net/0xb2c8e5/1/

```
yAxis: {
        tickPositioner: function(){
            return[0,30, 50, 100, 250];},
        tickPixelInterval: 1},
```

Use tickPixelInterval with value of one, and the only return the ticks you want to see.

Comment: Doesn't work... With "tickPixelInterval: number" i can choose the interval between all lines. But i want a tickPixelInterval for each lines. For example 30px between first line and second line... 50px between second line and third line... Do you understand? :)

Comment: That's exactly what those two options will do for you - you need to take a look at the examples and the two properties that are listed in the answer. 'tickPixelInterval' isn't part of the answer at all...

Comment: Where????? Tell me how is possible to change the distanze between first line and second line (100px for example), and between secondo e third lins (200 px).. I saw the example.

Comment: Using those functions/properties, you tell the chart exactly where to plot each tick/gridline. So you can put them wherever (however far apart) you want. Just like in the example(s).

Comment: but how ? :( is there a small example? the distance between lines will be  not equal for all lines of grid

Comment: You need to use tickPositioner, tickPixelInterval set distance between ticks globally.