# Change the distance between x-axis lables of a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, properties

I plot the following figure and I want to decrease the distance between x axis labels for example the distance between 1 and 2 or 2 and 3.
[image]

I do not know how can I do that !!!

I found these pages [1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/ticksdistance.html) and  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217476/how-to-change-the-distance-between-lines-of-grid) but I could not know how should I write those codes without getting exceptions. Since, I am not familiar with Matlab environment.

Comment: what do you mean decrease the distance? adding more ticks?

Comment: @Hamid I want to decrease the space between 1 and 2 in x-axis. For example, if the distance between 1 and 2 in x-axis is 1 cm; I can change it to 0.5 cm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is resize your figure or change it's position. It would change the distance.